# Quadrature Amplitude Modulation (QAM) 16

Tags: modulation, quadrature

How do we represent the most significant and least signuficant bits in QAM 16 as we do in QAM 4 with cos(x), -cos(x), sin(x), and -sin(x).

Then, by adding these waves we generate the final wave representing given combinations of bits. For example, if we have 00 we would add waves cos(x) and sin(x). If we have 01 we would add waves cos(x) and -sin(x), etc.

This final wave corresponds to a point on constellation diagram.

However, I am confused how we do this in QAM 16 where we have 4 bits per symbol, e.g. 0001? Do we still use the same cos(x), -cos(x), sin(x) and -sin(x)?

Comment: @Captainj2001 OK, I did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Q**uadrature **A**mplitude **M**odulation or **QAM** uses carriers that are in quadrature, i.e., 90\$^\circ\$ apart. Different weights (amplitude and sign) are applied to each carrier depending on the binary information transmitted. These can be visualized on what is called a constellation diagram as points in the complex plane. Both circular and rectangular QAM schemes are used, although rectangular schemes are more prevalent.

The scheme you are thinking about is **P**hase **S**hift **K**eying or **PSK**, and is typically not used above 8-PSK or 45\$^\circ\$ phasing.

> How are the bit locations assigned to a rectangular grid in **QAM**?

The answer to this question is that bits are mapped into the complex plane, after being demodulated from the carrier at the receiver you have a waveform that looks like,
$$
s(t) = 2A\cos(\omega_m) + 2B\sin(\omega_m),
$$
then this signal is demodulated by the respective in-phase and quadrature data mixers and low pass filtered to give the receiving tone. The DC signals are then separately sampled and is mapped to the complex plane as,
$$
s(t) = A + jB
$$
for rectangular QAM-16 the values \$A\$ and \$B\$ can take are \$\pm 1\$ and \$\pm 2\$. This corresponds to a rectangular grid of 4 points in each quadrant.

The topic of the actual hardware implementation of converting these points to a stream of digital data is a topic for another question.

Comment: How are bits represented in QAM 16? I know that in QAM 4 bits are represented with cos(x), -cos(x), sin(x), and -sin(x). Then, e.g. if 00 we will sum cos(x) and sin(x). However, how is that done with QAM 16 or higher?

Comment: @Navi: Did you make any attempt to [look it up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrature_amplitude_modulation#Rectangular_QAM) before you asked here?

Comment: @Dave Tweed Yes, I did. However, I still didn't find the answer I am looking. In QAM 16 or higher, how do we represent the most and least significant bits as we do in QAM 4?

Comment: @Navi the link Dave Tweed gave opens to a diagram of a QAM16 diagram that shows how the phase and amplitudes are mapped to the symbols binary value. I don't think the angle spacing has to be totally regular but perhaps could be chosen so as well to minimise harmonics or something.  There is bound to be more info on the net than one person can read in a year on just QAM-16.

Comment: @Captainj2001 What is $j$?

Comment: @Captainj2001 Additionally, with respect to the number of amplitudes and phases given QAM uses, is this correct: QAM 4 = 1 amplitudes, 4 phases;
QAM 8 = 2 amplitudes, 4 phases;
QAM 16 = 3 amplitudes, 12 phases;
QAM 32 = 5 amplitudes, 28 phases?

Comment: @Navi \$j = \sqrt{-1}\$. In terms of amplitudes and phases this depends how you think about phases. Only two carriers are used and they are 90\$^\circ\$ out of phase. Amplitudes of \$\pm A\$ are used, negative signs could be considered phases though. I think you may not be ready to understand complex envelope modulation schemes (QPSK/QAM) if you don't have a good grasp of complex analysis.

Comment: @Captainj2001 I think I understand. Please, correct me if I'm wrong: the value of the amplitude of modulated signal is modulus of a complex number $A+jB$ which also corresponds to the length of the hypotenuse. This is because the complex number can be expressed as a vector in Gauss plane. The QAM uses cosine (In-phase component) and sine (Quadrature component) waves and only amplitudes of these waves gets ($\pm A, \pm B$) changed in order to generate modulated wave.

Comment: @Navi Yes that's correct.